# Default value on Update

Tags: sql-server

I have a default datetime value (getdate) for a column, when I do insert the getdate() comes up and insert the current time, but I need to do the same when user update the record modifying this column as well, is there any way to do it like the insert without creating a trigger?

Comment: Can you show what the record would look like before the update and what you would like it to look like afterward?

Comment: You can encapsulate the update logic into stored procedures and update the date column as part of this sp call.

Comment: I found it, using DEFAULT in the column that I have the constraint is going to solve it. I'm not using stored procedures. Thanks

Comment: @rgx71 What?, how would that solve the column getting automatically updated without a trigger or without explicitely updating it?

Comment: Basically yes doing the update but using MODIFIED_DATE=DEFAULT

Answer (score 1):

Add it to your Update SQL statement:

```
UPDATE [YOUR_TABLE]
SET [COLUMN1] = [VALUE1], MODFIIED_DATE = GETDATE()
WHERE [YOUR_TABLE.ID] = @ID
```